# Howto: enable anonymous surveys in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to set up surveys for a public facing MOSS site that allows anonymous access.  I'm willing to live with the restrictions and have followed the instructions on the blog teuntostring- using-surveys-on-anonymous-access.htm  (I can't add the link here as I'm a new user) to the letter (I think).  However, I end up with a login prompt every time I try to access the survey.

Note that this is a publishing portal.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous people cannot contribute, in any form.

There are a couple of options as work around.

1) Use an infopath web form and have it submitted as a web service.  This does require that you write a web service to handle it, there are multiple examples of this around.

2) fake the web service with javascript and hard code account information.

3) have an account that anonymous users automaticly log in as, requires a handler.

see
http://blogs.devhorizon.com/reza/?p=551
http://www.elumenotion.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=11
http://wssguestaccount.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=12313